# Kendo UI intellisense working only on layout page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I got the Kendo UI intellisense working when I write script on _Layout.cshtml page, but when I want to use it from page utilizing this layout, then the intellisense is gone.

When I add the script kendo.all.min.js at the top of the page utilizing layout, intellisense is back. Such plumbing does not seem right + messes up the console debugging (says that this component was already loaded).

I'm talking about the Kendo UI intellisense (not the MVC helpers, which works ok). I added the below to _Layout.cshtml and it is normally registered in _ViewStart.cshtml.

```
<head>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/kendo/css")
    <script src="~/Scripts/kendo/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/kendo/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/kendo/kendo.all.min.js"></script>    
    <script src="~/Scripts/kendo/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: wild guess.. its only working on layout page cos when the script runs, the element on the layout is available to it and it initialises it.. but at that time the elements on ur page are not loaded

Comment: I think it should work on both, regardless if the element is instantiated on layout, or the page inheriting this layout...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a _references.js file containing:

```
/// <reference path="kendo/kendo.all.min.js" />
```

based on this article:
http://madskristensen.net/post/the-story-behind-_referencesjs

It did the job.